When switching branches with different submodule HEAD, when does git _not_ automatically update the submodule?
When you have a submodule in your repository and on different branches it has different HEADs, sometimes git updates the submodule when switching between branches, sometimes it does not.
In the latter case, the submodule then appears as an unstaged change from <HEAD on the current branch> to <HEAD on the previous branch>. On git submodule update, the change disappears.
I know and consider intended, that git does not update the submodule, if it has local modifications. git submodule update fails in this case, warning that it would destroy work. - This is very good.
This question is specifically about the case that:

before checkout, git status shows no changes
after checkout, git status shows submodule changed, with the HEAD from <previous branch> as the unstaged modification

Might this be a bug? I have seen this behaviour on git version 2.30.2 and several earlier ones. - But it does not always happen and there seems to be no rhyme nor reason to when it does.
Sample case, 'Libraries/HCL' is the submodule:
$ git status
On branch 82-deploy-step-not-being-executed
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/82-deploy-step-not-being-executed'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean
$ git submodule status
  36f3be901ce94cb6137829d47bb397f1516b5834 Libraries/HCL (quickstep-development)
$ git checkout published_release
M   Libraries/HCL
Switched to branch 'published_release'
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/published_release'.
$ git status
On branch published_release
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/published_release'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
    modified:   Libraries/HCL (new commits)

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
$ git diff
diff --git a/Libraries/HCL b/Libraries/HCL
index bb41d762..36f3be90 160000
--- a/Libraries/HCL
+++ b/Libraries/HCL
@@ -1 +1 @@
-Subproject commit bb41d762373828945cfd2f8a7c4eb9285111510e
+Subproject commit 36f3be901ce94cb6137829d47bb397f1516b5834
$ git submodule update
Submodule path 'Libraries/HCL': checked out 'bb41d762373828945cfd2f8a7c4eb9285111510e'
$ git status
On branch published_release
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/published_release'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean

